# Assigning string with null terminators inside it in one line in C

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to assign a string which includes null terminators within the string as well as the end in one go. I am able to assign it manually, char by char, but is there a way to do this in one go? I looked for a similar question but couldn't find one.

Where I'm stuck.
EX:

```
char *argvppp = (char *)malloc(14);
argvppp = "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0"; // forward slash before the 10 after the null terminator
```

When I try to read from argvppp, like this:

```
printf("%s\n", argvppp);
printf("%s\n", argvppp+5);
printf("%s\n", argvppp+8);
printf("%s", argvppp+11);
```

This is what I get:

```
mine
-c
/10
[blank]
```

And when I try to just not escape it like this:

```
argvppp = "mine\0-c\010\0/2.0\0"; // no forward slash before the 10
```

This is what I get:

```
mine
-c
[blank]
.0
```

Is there a reliable way to do this without having to manually assign assign char by char?

What does work:

```
argvppp[0] = 'm';
argvppp[1] = 'i';
argvppp[2] = 'n';
argvppp[3] = 'e';
argvppp[4] = '\0';
argvppp[5] = '-';
argvppp[6] = 'c';
argvppp[7] = '\0';
argvppp[8] = '1';
argvppp[9] = '0';
argvppp[10] = '\0';
argvppp[11] = '2';
argvppp[12] = '.';
argvppp[13] = '0';
argvppp[14] = '\0';
```

I'm just wondering if there would be a way around this manual method.

Comment: You have a memory leak. First you assigned the pointer returned by `malloc()`, then you replaced it with a pointer to the string literal. Did you want to copy the string literal into the allocated memory?

Comment: @Barmar No, I wasn't trying to copy the string literal. I'm trying to malloc space and then  initialize the malloced space to those values.

Comment: You don't use `=` to copy strings. You use `strcpy()` or `memcpy()`.

Comment: You can't initialize malloced space, except by using `calloc()`, which initializes it to all 0. If you want to put something into the malloced space, you have to copy it.

Comment: `\010` is a single character with the character code 8, not `\0` followed by `10`

Comment: I'm now using memcpy, and I'm getting the same output. I already malloced 14 bytes for argvppp.
    memcpy(argvppp, "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0", 14);
output is 
mine
-c
/10
[blank]

Comment: The one with the forward slashes has more than 14 bytes. Use `sizeof` so you don't have to worry about miscounting.

Comment: You probably shouldn't put `\0` at the end. String literals automatically get a null byte at the end, you don't need to write one explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `memcpy()`

```
char *argvppp = malloc(sizeof "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0");
memcpy(argvppp, "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0", sizeof "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0");
```

When you don't put a `/` between `\0` and `10`, you get a single character `\010`. You can solve this by splitting the string literal apart.

```
"mine\0-c\0" "10\0/2.0\0"
```

Adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated.

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonders! With this suggestion I also needed to add a space between the NULL terminator and 2.0, but it worked with:

memcpy(argvppp, "mine\0-c\0" "10\0" "2.0\0", sizeof "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0");

Comment: You need to split it after `sizeof` as well. Defining a macro as in the other asnwer is a good idea.

Comment: I did split it in sizeof as well, but forgot to mention that here. Thank you very much!

Oh, I see what you mean, I did forget to split it within memcpy's sizeof

Comment: To have automatically the same string in both the allocation and the copy, `#define` the string as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

`=` does not copy the string only assigns the pointer to string literal to your variable. The memory allocated is lost. `string literals` cannot be modified as it invokes UB (undefined behaviour)

You need to copy the string literal into the memory referenced by te pointer:

```
define STR "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0";

char *argvppp = malloc(sizeof(STR));
memcpy(argvppp, STR, sizeof(STR));
```

you can also:

```
char argvppp[] = "mine\0-c\0/10\0/2.0\0";
```

Comment: `strcpy()` stops at the first null byte, so it won't copy the whole `STR`.

Comment: @Barmar did not notice those `\0`s. Thanks

Comment: The explicit example (char by char) shown in the OP would seem to indicate that the '/' in the "string-ish" version was some part of an experiment. One sees what one sees. OP again: "What does work is..." :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this where your data is clearly visible.

```
int main() {
    char *segs[] = { "mine", "-c", "10", "2.0" };
    char buf[ 50 ]; // long enough?!
    char *at = buf;

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof segs/sizeof segs[0]; i++ )
        at += sprintf( at, "%s", seg[i] ) + 1; // NB +1 is beyond '\0'

    /* Then examine the contents of 'buf[]' character by character. */        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it related to the question?

Comment: @0___________ Quoting the OP, `"I'm just wondering if there would be a way around this manual method."`... Depends on what you see when you read something.